# how to put more than one number in a line for for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for i in range(2, 101):
if i > 1: # Prime numbers are greater than 1
    for j in range(2, i):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            print(i,"is a composite number")
            break
        else:
            print(i,"is a prime number")
```

The program runs like the following:

`2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 is a composite number
5 is a prime number
6 is a composite number
7 is a prime number
8 is a composite number
9 is a composite number
10 is a composite number
...`

My question is: how do we put composite numbers on the same line and prime numbers on one line

In other words, how to do something like this:

`4,6... is all composite numbers`

and

`2,3,5... is all prime numbers`

Comment: You have to save the primes and composites in two separate lists as you go along and print both at the end, unless you want to do twice the computation.

Comment: Create two lists, one for primes and one for composits, and put the numbers into them instead of printing. After the loop, you can print the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in lists:

```
primes = []
composites = []
for i in range(2, 101):
    if i > 1: # Prime numbers are greater than 1
        for j in range(2, i):
            if (i % j) == 0:
                composites.append(i)
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)

print("Composites: ", *composites)
print("Primes: ", *primes)
```

The only fancy-ish part of this is the `splat`. By writing  `print("Composites: ", *composites)` with the `*` we print without the `[]` brackets.

Gives:

```
Composites:  4 6 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 18 20 21 22 24 25 26 27 28 30 32 33 34 35 36 38 39 40 42 44 45 46 48 49 50 51 52 54 55 56 57 58 60 62 63 64 65 66 68 69 70 72 74 75 76 77 78 80 81 82 84 85 86 87 88 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 98 99 100
Primes:  2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```